# JavaScript: windows.external with custom function for chrome, firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one JavaScript file which is calling some external function(Function in different file) using windows.external like

```
 windows.external.setValue('Hi');
```

But above only work in IE. I want same functionality in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

After googling I got following conclusion:

We can define function in parent js or html file, and 
call in following way:

```
 Chrome/Firefox --> window.parent.customFunction()
             IE --> window.external.customFunction()
```